# Slowly expanding Quick Find window bug in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition (Version 10.0.30319.1), I noticed tonight that for some reason I kept getting a wider window for quick find. I verified by exiting, restarting and retesting the bug conditions.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Open existing project (I don't think it matters which one)
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and give it something to search for (<kbd>></kbd>?) in "current document"
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>
6. Go to Step 4.

Can you reproduce a slowly expanding quick find window? Do I have some sort of wacky bugged out system?

[A bug has been opened](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558525/quick-find-window-resize) on Connect Tracker.

Comment: Some additional details might help.  You have a text editor window open, right?  Is the file being edited part of the project?  Is it a particular programming language?

Comment: Post the Connect URL after you submit the bug so people can upvote if they're able to reproduce it.

Comment: It's a known bug.  I don't know if there is a connect bug on it, but I do know we have one internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This has been fixed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/patch-available-for-the-growing-find-and-replace-dialog/):

> One of our top reported Microsoft Connect  issues since RTM has been that the Find and Replace dialog grows 16px on each use.  On repeated use, this can quickly take up your entire screen real estate.  We now have a patch available for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps above using Visual Studio Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel and could not reproduce your bug.

Comment: I'm using resharper (this could have an impact), and I cannot reproduce

Comment: I'm not using Resharper (waiting for 5.1EAP). But good info, thanks. I think they write their own don't they?

Comment: I am also using Resharper.  Solution: Buy/install Resharper :-)

Comment: I am waiting on 5.1EAP cause the aspx bug is pissing me off or I wouldn't have come across this bug ;)

Comment: Check closely - I didn't think I was reproducing the bug at first, but close inspection showed that the find/replace box was expanding by about 2 character widths per use.  Also close the find/replace box between uses (this wasn't mentioned in the original post, although I guess it was implied.)

Comment: Yeah, when I hit enter it was closing the box (I might have altered a setting for that, idk) ... Or so I thought, that was at work, at home now.

Comment: Darel is right.  I tried this again using JRuler and found that it expands a little bit each time, regardless of Resharper.

Comment: @Ben Hoffstein ~ @Darel ~ Feel free to visit the connect.microsoft.com link and upvote the bug so they know it reoccurs ;)